# HTML5: why Websocket works over ws:// but it doesn't over wss://?

Tags: php, html, web-services

I know i probably wont get any answers here but here is my shot.

basically I'm using this code [HERE](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket/comment-page-1)

I can make it all work fine on my server using **ws://** (insecure connection) but when i switch to **wss://** (secured connection) I cannot connect and i get the following error:

```
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

This is my wss:// code:

```
var wsUri = "wss://example.com:443/websocket/server.php";
```

and this is my insecure ws:// connection (works)

```
var wsUri = "ws://example.com:9000/websocket/server.php";
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong to be honest. could someone please advise on this issue?

I am starting the websocket server (server.php) via SSH and this is what I see when i start is:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Sec-WebSocket-Key in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 175
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 56
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 57
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 58
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Sec-WebSocket-Key in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 175
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 56
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 57
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 58
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Sec-WebSocket-Key in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 175
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 56
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 57
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 58
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Sec-WebSocket-Key in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 175
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 56
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 57
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 58
PHP Warning:  socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [104]: Connection reset by peer in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 52
PHP Warning:  socket_getpeername(): unable to retrieve peer name [107]: Transport endpoint is not connected in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 100
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Sec-WebSocket-Key in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 175
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 56
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 57
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 58
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Sec-WebSocket-Key in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 175
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 56
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 57
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 58
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Sec-WebSocket-Key in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 175
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 56
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 57
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 58
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Sec-WebSocket-Key in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 175
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 56
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 57
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 58
PHP Warning:  socket_recv(): unable to read from socket [104]: Connection reset by peer in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 52
PHP Warning:  socket_getpeername(): unable to retrieve peer name [107]: Transport endpoint is not connected in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/websocket/server.php on line 100
```

I assume most of the errors will disappear if i get the first error sorted but i don't really understand what that means and don't know what i need to do about it!

And now the error changed to :

```
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

**This is my full server.php code:**

```
<?php
$host = 'example.com'; //host
$port = '9000'; //port
$null = NULL; //null var

//Create TCP/IP sream socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
//reuseable port
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

//bind socket to specified host
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);

//listen to port
socket_listen($socket);

//create & add listning socket to the list
$clients = array($socket);

//start endless loop, so that our script doesn't stop
while (true) {

//usleep(500000);


    //manage multipal connections
    $changed = $clients;
    //returns the socket resources in $changed array
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

    //check for new socket
    if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
        $socket_new = socket_accept($socket); //accpet new socket
        $clients[] = $socket_new; //add socket to client array

        $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024); //read data sent by the socket
        perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port); //perform websocket handshake

        socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip); //get ip address of connected socket
        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' connected'))); //prepare json data
        send_message($response); //notify all users about new connection

        //make room for new socket
        $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
        unset($changed[$found_socket]);
    }

    //loop through all connected sockets
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) { 

        //check for any incomming data
        while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
        {
            $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
            $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
            $user_name = $tst_msg->name; //sender name
            $user_message = $tst_msg->message; //message text
            $user_color = $tst_msg->color; //color

            //prepare data to be sent to client
            $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'usermsg', 'name'=>$user_name, 'message'=>$user_message, 'color'=>$user_color)));
            send_message($response_text); //send data



//////////////////////
            include_once "connect.php";

            $lat = substr($user_message, 0, strpos($user_message, ','));


            $lon = substr($user_message, strpos($user_message, ",") + 1);    


            $sqlu1="UPDATE `orders` SET dlat='$lat', dlng='$lon' WHERE `driverId`='$user_name'";
            $queryu1 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlu1);   

            $sqlu="UPDATE `cars` SET lat='$lat', lng='$lon' WHERE `login_pin`='$user_name'";
            $queryu = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlu);

////////////////////////////////





        break 2; //exist this loop  

        }






        $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
        if ($buf === false) { // check disconnected client
            // remove client for $clients array
            $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
            socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
            unset($clients[$found_socket]);

            //notify all users about disconnected connection
            $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
            send_message($response);
        }
    }
}

// close the listening socket
socket_close($socket);

function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    foreach($clients as $changed_socket)
    {
        @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}


//Unmask incoming framed message
function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

//Encode message for transfer to client.
function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

//handshake new client.
function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));
    //hand shaking header
    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: wss://$host:$port/websocket/shout.php\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you set a certificate on the server?

Comment: @damienc, ofcourse. the server has the SSL installed and the domain is accessible properly via https://

Comment: Some people have the same problem in the comment feed of the original post. Can you manage to get some logs of the server application?

Comment: have you check the website with a ssl checker like https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html ?

Comment: @MaximeK, yes i did a few times before posting this question and everything came back as normal with a green tick next to them!

Comment: @damienc, what logs are you referring to? the error logs?

Comment: @Jackson Yes, app or webserver (if any).

Comment: @damienc, Edited my question.

Comment: @damienc, is port 443 or 9000 correct at all? I don't know which port to use when i use wss://

Comment: the port 9000 works fine with ws://

Comment: @Jackson I had a problem like that, i replaced the wss by https opened the page and tell the browser to trust this page.

Comment: @MaximeK, i haven't tried that but even if that works... that would only work for me! what happens to other users from other location/machines/IPS etc?

Comment: @Jackson did you use a real certificate or its a self signed one ?, because this happend for self signed certif only :)

Comment: @MaximeK, i used 'Let's Encrypt'. Let's Encrypt is a certificate authority (CA) that allows you to create a free SSL certificate for your domain.

Comment: @Jackson Ok, and have you an updated browser, Its like less than 1 years its a certificate authority :)

Comment: @MaximeK, yes i have updated browser and also I have 8 months left of my certificate.

Comment: have you solved the problem ?